# When a Security Deposit needs to be used

Tags: single-word-requests

When a tenant doesn't pay rent, he [forfeits](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/forfeit) his security deposit (bond).

But what is it called from the landlord's side? Surely he isn't forfeiting the deposit.

What is the correct word?

> The landlord was patient for three weeks, but ultimately had to ______________ the deposit.

P.S. I'm looking for the word used in AmE. Any others are welcome but please note which English your answer is in.

Comment: maybe 'seize', or 'keep'.

Comment: A deposit is not a fine, it is a collateral. The landlord may ***seize*** it to cover his expenses, but he doesn't gain ownership of it. There's no symmetry here.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "**claim**".

The following is taken from the [Consumer Affairs Victoria website](https://www.consumer.vic.gov.au/housing/renting/ending-a-lease-or-residency/claiming-the-bond-tenants-and-residents/overview):

> When a tenancy ends the tenant may receive the whole bond, or only a part of it, **if the landlord claims the money** to cover any damages caused to the property.

This also aligns with what I was taught in Legal Studies. Note that the bond is the equivalent to your "security deposit".

### Other Terms

I notice that the OP has since updated their question to specify that they would like American terms. I took it upon myself to search for "landlord security deposit" on the American version of Google, and found an American general-reference law site that had a [page on security deposits](http://realestate.findlaw.com/landlord-tenant-law/what-can-a-landlord-deduct-from-a-security-deposit-for-cleaning.html).

Based on this page, these *could* be possible options. However, I'm not overly familiar with American law.

- **hold on to**

> Sometimes a security deposit is called a "damage deposit," and is generally some **amount of money that the landlord is able to hold on to** if a rental property needs any cleaning or repairs, in order to return the property to the condition it was in when the renter first moved in.

- **withhold**
- **retain**

> [If a landlord does not return all of your security deposit, you may be able to sue.] This action, allowed by security deposit laws, is generally called a **Wrongful Withholding of Security Deposit or a Wrongful Retention of Security Deposit lawsuit**. If you do decide to take legal action, you may be able to recover all or some of your security deposit.